# How to resolve this react dependency issue? React 18.1.0 -- @react-aria/ssr

Tags: reactjs, dependencies

I am  part of a small group who is making a project with  backend: Aspnetcore webapi and Frontend React - Bootstrap (+Axios to get API data)
But no matter what i do I keep getting

invalid: "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1" from node_modules/@restart/ui/node_modules/@react-aria/ssr

full image:
[invalid error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gktjo.png)

I tried  various online suggestions:

- remove package.lock.json
- remove node-modules
- npm install

I tried downgrading react but than the other modules  'complain'

Any suggestions how to fix this?

packages.json:

[packages.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpEkK.png)

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Greetings

Comment: [Please include errors and config as formatted text rather than links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: First thing to try would be using a later react-bootstrap; current is 2.4, or downgrading react and fixing other dependencies.

Comment: @DaveNewton thx,  the issue  is still there but for some reason my page does show everything  now (after VS restart).  I will see if this problem comes back after implementing my axios again and if it doesnt, this can be closed.